# Android edittext invisible password

Tags: android, android-edittext, passwords

i have an password edittext with this property :

android:inputType="textPassword"

I want to mask typed chars in edittext with dots but in default way android shows typed chars , how to mask them and prevent to be shown at first (just like html password fields) ?

Comment: To be clear, you are using `android:inputType="textPassword"` already, but you want to also prohibit it from temporarily showing the most recently typed character for a brief moment _as well_? Correct?

Comment: if the answer to @Jon Adams' question is a Yes, why would you want to change the behavior that Android users are used to?

Comment: @liminal i want to prevent screen recorders from capturing passwords in my app

Comment: RE preventing screen recorders: Are you also sure you're preventing all on-screen keyboards too? Otherwise, this hack won't stop that security issue. Are you positive you can stop all external key loggers from external keyboards or custom downloaded keyboards? It's fairly excepted that it is not the responsibility of the app to prevent those security wholes since they are outside the control of your app, and is up to the Android system and user to ensure they do not have malicious recorders/loggers on their system.

Comment: @JonAdams yes i'm using my own keypad that does not have any pressed button hover or etc . At least i want to observance this plan

Answer (score 2):

I think this could be done with a TextWatcher. It's a listener that you would set on your editText. In particular the method 'beforeTextChanged'. You would be able to store off what they have typed internally and replace the string with whatever character you wish.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html